# AngularJS dynamically pass in both a directive name and a value , I can do one or the other , not both

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Goal: Pass in a db driven   1. directive name and a  2. value

Want to do I compile a dynamic directive AND pass in a value as well.
Below the **{{dir.Tag}}**  example would be a real directive name with a textbox and this works  ,  however , I NEED to be able to pass in extra things in order to have no so generic of a textbox,  like value and conditions and the ng-model etc..

HTML with loop

```
<div ng-repeat="dir in vm.liberty2[vm.q].directive">
     div compile-directive="{{dir.Tag}}"></div><br><br>
</div>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('cal').directive('compileDirective', function ($compile) {
   return function (scope, element, attrs) {
       element.html(attrs.compileDirective);
       $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };
});
```

**How can I also pass in a value ?**

Comment: use ng-init to declare a variable and then try passing. or. use bindToController with @, = or & .

Comment: Can you explain more on this for a better understanding?